# Утилита генерирующая случайные контактные данные пользователей из заданного региона

Tags: ruby

Кто может подсказать как попроще сделать?

На языке Ruby требуется разработать утилиту, принимающую 3 параметра в командной строке — регион (один из трех: US, RU, BY), количество записей (натуральное число, 1..1000000) и вероятность того, что конкретная запись содержит ошибку (вещественной число, 0..1) — и генерирующую случайные контактные данные пользователей из заданного региона.

Требования. Записи при заданном запуске не должны повторяться. Части адреса и телефон должны соответствовать друг другу (например, ZIP code должен быть согласован со штатом и телефоном, индекс 224012 должен соотвествовать адресу в Бресте и т.д. — простого использования гемов as is может быть недостаточно). Ошибка генерируется случайным образом как одно из следующих преобразований: перестановка двух соседних цифр, замена цифры на другую, удаление буквы, дублирование буквы, перестановка соседних букв, вставка буквы.

Comment: @Nata9999, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

---

Судя по заданию и языку программирования это даже не университетское задание - это что, тестовое на собеседовании?

Answer (score 1):

используй FactoryGirl и FFaker -- два этих гема решат половину задачи.